# What Happened in the Triskelion after Captain America smashed it with the Helicarrier

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, captain-america, agents-of-shield

I have been wondering for a long time,What happened to the Triskelion (S.H.I.E.L.D Headquarters) after the Helicarrier in *Captain America:The Winter Soldier*.I watched a separate TV installment (*Agents of Shield*), and in Season 2 there was brief footage of Coulson in his office watching the events of the Helicarrier smashing into the Triskelion.

What exactly happened after the Helicarrier smashed into the Triskelion?

Comment: Considering what happened to SHIELD, I suspect it was demolished

Comment: Immediately after the helicarrier crashed, there was running and screaming.

Answer (score 4):

#### Given the state of SHIELD after their discovery of HYDRA, the Triskelion was probably destroyed by the government due to the damage done by the crashing Helicarrier on the building and surrounding premises.

- In addition, the collateral damage and classified material (from the crashing helicarriers) likely had the area cordoned off while it was cleared of classified technologies.
- In the video below, the building appeared to have suffered enough structural damage to consider the building unsafe for occupancy.

Comment: It was also cleaned up by Damage Control.

Comment: In addition, an alternate version of the Triskelion appeared in The Framework. Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. explains a lot of this.